# Microsoft Access database connection using XMLHTTP

Tags: rest, ms-access, api-design

In

[Creating a Microsoft Access database connection to a REST-based API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768235/creating-a-microsoft-access-database-connection-to-a-rest-based-api)

on this line...

```vbs
httpReq.Open "GET", "http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN", False
```

I noticed that he points to `rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN`.

My question is "Is this a file of sorts? or is it a service?" I am trying to achieve the same thing in my access application.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is this a file of sorts? or is it a service?"

It is an endpoint for a web service (in this case, a RESTful web service). It is the web address from which we can retrieve the information for a particular person (whose ID is 'KOSTE-ARIN') in the ARIN database.

Whether you think of it as retrieving a "file" or as retrieving "the result of a database query" the effect is the same: You send the `GET` request to that particular address (endpoint) and the server returns a big long string containing Mr. Kosters' information.

Comment: Aha, Thank you very much Gord, Now I understand :-) I do actually have a service that was initially created for .Net applications, this was created by a friend of mine who had done this for me. But cannot do this any more. I suppose I would have to have a new one for my access application? Or is there a possible way that..."If i have the correct details for the service" I can use the same service to connect my access application through the service? and how would i point to the service....

Comment: Example "mydomain.com/MyServiceFolder" Or do I have to point to the service file I.E or "Mydomain.com/Myservice.svc"? Thank you again for your help.