# Create ODBC wrapper/driver for REST API

Tags: json, rest, odbc

just checking before i build the wheel

I need a hackjob to present an api endpoint in a database. It doesn't need to do anything fancy, just convert what the rest api spits out into a single column of json. A new row at each iteration at the root/top level would be nice but a single varchar or whatever would be ok too

Does an ODBC wrapper exist out there anywhere? Googling just brings up hits for doing the opposite (exposing databases as an api). I'm not interested in the simba etc paid stuff. The consumer is SQL server so i can just use xp_cmdshell with curl as a last resort

so for instance the output of this : http://jsonapiplayground.reyesoft.com/v2/authors could come out as a table like so (a row for each author)

```
|data                                             |
---------------------------------------------------
|{
            "type": "authors",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Madge Mohr DVM 2",
                "date_of_birth": "1977-08-21",
                "date_of_death": "2009-09-14"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "photos": {
                    "data": []
                },
                "books": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "41"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/v2/authors/1"
            }
        }                                         |
---------------------------------------------------
|{
            "type": "authors",
            "id": "3",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Zelma Ortiz DDS",
                "date_of_birth": "1992-09-06",
                "date_of_death": "2000-12-19"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "photos": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "photos",
                            "id": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "books": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "36"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "48"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/v2/authors/3"
            }
        }|
----------
|{
            "type": "authors",
            "id": "4",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Fermin Barrows Sr.",
                "date_of_birth": "1991-03-18",
                "date_of_death": "1975-11-07"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "photos": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "photos",
                            "id": "4"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "books": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "26"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "44"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "46"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/v2/authors/4"
            }
        }|
----------
|{
            "type": "authors",
            "id": "5",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Terry Durgan",
                "date_of_birth": "2011-03-06",
                "date_of_death": "2017-04-13"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "photos": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "photos",
                            "id": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "books": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "16"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "50"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/v2/authors/5"
            }
        }|
----------
|{
            "type": "authors",
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Annalise Walsh",
                "date_of_birth": "2004-11-27",
                "date_of_death": "1997-07-20"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "photos": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "photos",
                            "id": "6"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "books": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "books",
                            "id": "21"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/v2/authors/6"
            }
        }|
---------
```

Comment: Commenting, but will also flag to close since this is asking for a product recommendation. My employer creates ODBC drivers for REST APIs: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/rest; https://www.cdata.com/drivers/json

Comment: not really asking for a product recommendation, link to a guide or a github or something. And we don't have a few grand for the cdata drivers - we reached out last year and that was the quote.

Comment: did you find a solution that worked for you? I am also not looking for a product, but a guide/repo where someone has hacked it together.

Comment: no we ended up using a different approach to getting the data. But if i did need to do it myself i think i'd use mssql & a generic .netclr function that takes the api url as the parameter. It could spit out the output in a single column in a table valued function that can be queried using sql server oledb, jdbc, odbc etc drivers

Comment: Also looking for a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768235/creating-a-microsoft-access-database-connection-to-a-rest-based-api[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768235/creating-a-microsoft-access-database-connection-to-a-rest-based-api) see above...