# Catalog of HTTP commands, methods, etc. for Microsoft Access 365

Tags: rest, ms-access

I am developing an app in Microsoft Access 365. My intention is to have it perform HTTP commands to read data in a long string and convert it to a record. I actually want to perform queries on-demand to retrieve multiple records in order to minimize connection resource usage on the server with my READ requests. In order to develop this subsystem, I would like to know where a reference guide is that explains what all the HTTP-related MS Access commands are, with examples, so I can learn how to do this myself. I understand that, on the surface of things, there are only about four HTTP commands that are regularly used. My problem is finding the reference guide that will explain how to use the MS Access language to interface to a web server. Whether the data returned is in XML or text, I'd like to be able to work with both formats, but I'd prefer XML. So far, I haven't had any success searching either Google or Bing.

Thanks
Steve/Jazz Engineer

Comment: There is no such reference. The source determines what commands to use, not Access.

Comment: Gustav, I understand that the web site I'll be interrogating has a defined API and that I would use that API to interact with the web site. But VBA has relevant methods. Consider the following:

' VBA project Reference required:
' Microsoft XML, v3.0

Dim httpReq As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
httpReq.Open "GET", "http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN", False
httpReq.send
Dim response As String
response = httpReq.responseText
Debug.Print response

Are you saying that (i.e.) MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP is part of the target site's API? Or that it's all HTTP?

Comment: The VBA code is never part of the API, it just has to adopt to the specifications of the API. Also, a normal web page is not an API - it is a page to retrieve and parse. How to do this depends on the content of the retrieved data.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32768235/2144390) help?

Answer (score 0):

The desktop version of Access or the 365 version are idential in nature, and have ZERO features in regards to the web, and ZERO features in regards to a Http interface.

You can no more execute HTTP commands against a power-point file sitting in 365 or your desktop then you can against a plane jane text file or in this case Access.

Access is just a file sitting on a computer, and to use the database you must have the JET (now called ACE) database engine installed on the client and you require a full windows qualified path name to that file, and you also need to be able to OPEN that file directly with the windows operating system.

You do not connect to a text file, and you do not connect to a Access file. You OPEN such files and read them. As such HTTP has zero ability to open a file, and HTTP has zero ability to open a file.

You can connect to a server type of database like SQL server or say MySQL. These systems only require a TC/IP socket connection and you NEVER actually open a file when using SQL server - but ONLY connect to a "service".

Access is not a service or it is a process that runs on the remote server. It is a plane jane file sitting on that system, and to read data from such files, you need the ability to OPEN the file, and HTTP does not provide file open services.

A horse is a horse is a horse.

A file is a file is a file.

To use and interact with a Access database you have to OPEN that file and be able to read the contents. HTTP and in fact even FTP does not provide this ability to open a file and read the contents. FTP can download a WHOLE file, but cannot open and read a file.

So, a word document sitting on a web site can be consumed because Word or a text file, or even a power-point file? They are WHOLE file based and when you modify 1 thing in say Excel, then the WHOLE file can be saved back to the server.

In the case of Access? it does NOT operate as a single file like say Excel. You are able to modify one row in the file - and when you do so, you note that no file save commad exists nor is even required in Access.

So, Access is strictly a 100% file based system, and as such FTP or HTTP use of such files is not possbile - anymore then you can update a simple text file over HTTP.

If access was not a file base system, and was a "service" based system like SQL server etc, then connection to that service could occur, and in fact it could occur without you needing to have Access. You are able to interact with a web site with any browser - it is the web server that then interacts with the database, but you NEVER open the database file client side. You can order a book on Amazon, but your client side is NEVER directly opening and interacting with the database. (hey, that would be cool - you open the amazon database directly and read all customers data!!!!).

So, you can no more use HTTP to interact with a database then you can use HTTP to open and read files on the web server. Such web servers can dish out a whole file. So you could place a access database on a web server and when you click on it, then the whole accDB file (or Excel file, or text file) can be downloaded to the client for consumption.  Of course if you modify that Excel file, then when done, you can save it back to the web server, but you will be overwriting the existing copy. As a result, the last person to save will be the only updated copy.

So, such a setup could allow one user to update a access file. The file would travel to client. You edit, you play, and when done you save the WHOLE FILE back. As such, this system would not allow multiple users to work at the same time.

But, to be clear:
You can no more use HTTP to update a text file, a word file or a Access file. To update such files you have to download the whole file local. As such, then that file will be opned and used and modified local. and thus as such these systems do not and would not perfmit mutli-users to update a single file at the same time.

When Access is used by multiple users at the same time, then each workstation does NOT open or load the whole file, but opens the file directly and modifies parts of that file. The key concept is the ability to modify parts at the same time. So one user can edit a row because the file open command ONLY modifies that part of the file. Other users who have that same file open are thus ALSO modifying the same file. So this ability to modify a PART of the file with more then one user is the difference between a file based system like word, or Excel or in this case Access.

With a server based system like SQL server, then each client NEVER opens the file, and NEVER interacts directly to that file on the server, but ONLY interacts with a "service" that runs on the server. But of course Access being file based? There is no service running on the server that can open and interact with the Access file for you.

This does suggest you could build some web service calls that you send (or receive) data from the web server, and those web service calls you make could in fact interact with the Access database for you. However, such a web service would be a custom web service you write, and those simple base low cost 365 accounts don't provide the means to write and develop your own custom web services that could in theory accept HTTP commands (via rest, or SOAP).

So the simple solution here is to adopt a database that also allows interaction via a service - SQL on Azure is one such example - but it certainly not the case with ms-access.

So MS-Access is not a server baseed technology and it not a server "service" running type of system either. It is a plane jane file sitting on a disk drive and as such these plane jane file based systems do not have anything to do with the web, or HTTP commands.

You can no more use HTTP commands against QuickBooks or any other file based desktop program - and that includes power-point or Excel or in this case MS-Access.

A file is a file is a file!